# Does the class (of the cached-value) needs to implement Serializable in Google Guava Cache?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using Google Guava Cache to store class of type let's say LevelOneDTO. Now this class is extending from LevelTwoDTO, which in turn extends from 2 more levels.

When I use a Google Guava Cache instance of type Cache<String, LevelOneDTO>, where String represents the UUID of LevelOneDTO and use it, I find that there are some issues reading the values of some of the fields in the LevelOneDTO. This has caused some issues wherein, when retrieved the one of the values, some of the fields in the LevelOneDTO objects are missing.

Thinking that the Guava Cache may be serializing/de-serializing the object while storing and reading from it, I added "implements Serializable" to all 4 levels of class hierarchy, and voila! It seems to work as well!

But I could not find any reference documentation where it says that the type/class of value to be stored needs to be serializable? Can someone shed some light on it?

I believe I have found the solution wherein adding "implements Serializable" (as I am using Java) solves the problem but I don't know WHY it is solving the problem, or couldn't find any documentation related to the need of that. Can someone throw some light on it?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The Guava cache doesn't do any serialization or anything. It doesn't document it because it doesn't happen.